# htacces rewrite rule for SSL for only one site in shared hosting site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have 2 sites w/ shared Linux hosting at Godaddy, and one is the root, and the other is in a subdirectory from root.  Lets call them Site-A and Site-B, with Site-B in the subdirectory off Site-A.  All is working fine.

I just installed a SSL certificate for Site-A, which works.  I want to use https for all traffic on Site-A, and I implemented the following in my root level .htaccess file:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This worked great on Site-A.  However, it causes Site-B to get an invalid certificate error/warning.  So, I disabled this in my .htaccess, and am not redirecting anything at present.

My question is - how can I create the rewriteCond so that this only select Site-A?  Related to this, what is the best practice for testing items like this, as I don't have a certificate in my test environment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm still having a problem with it, and I would like to write the rule to exclude Site-B from the rule, but I've been trying different things, and still can't get it to work correctly.

Comment: I was able to fix it with a 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site-A/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Site-A/?
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```